# Is there any way I can dry out this file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arraylist

Take a look at my files, the one thing that is bothering me for the moment is the repeated section and panel. I must not be able to see the bigger picture, so can anyone tell me a better and dryer method to code?

```
$(function() {

let pent = {
    init : function () {
        this.cacheDom();
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    cacheDom: function () {
        this.$el = $('#naver');
        this.$button = this.$el.find('#xCancel');
        this.$set = this.$el.find(".setting");
        this.$section = [
            this.$sectionA = this.$el.find('#set1'),
            this.$sectionB = this.$el.find('#set2'),
            this.$sectionC = this.$el.find('#set3'),
            this.$sectionD = this.$el.find('#set4')                
        ];            
        this.$panelA = this.$el.find('#settbox1');
        this.$panelB = this.$el.find('#settbox2');
        this.$panelC = this.$el.find('#settbox3');
        this.$panelD = this.$el.find('#settbox4');

    },
     bindEvents: function () {
        this.$button.on('click', this.hidePanel.bind(this));             
        this.$sectionA.on('click', this.showPanelA.bind(this));
        this.$sectionB.on('click', this.showPanelB.bind(this));
        this.$sectionC.on('click', this.showPanelC.bind(this));
        this.$sectionD.on('click', this.showPanelD.bind(this));
     },
     showPanelA: function () {
        this.$button.show();
        this.$panelA.slideDown(100);            
     },
     showPanelB: function () {
        this.$button.show();
        this.$panelB.slideDown(100);            
     },
     showPanelC: function () {
        this.$button.show();
        this.$panelC.slideDown(100);            
     },
     showPanelD: function () {
        this.$button.show();
        this.$panelD.slideDown(100);            
     },
     hidePanel : function () {
        this.$set.slideUp(100);
        this.$button.hide();
     },
};

pent.init();

});
```

Comment: For starters ids are unique in a page so all the `this.$el.find(someId)` can be simplified to `$(someId)` and you should be able to cut out the function duplications by passing parameters to a generic function which would also mean you wouldn't need to store so many variables also

Comment: Using common classes for common elements would cut out a lot of redundancy also. To be honest this could probably be cut down to about 8-10 lines of code

Comment: this question might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better code would be:

```
$('#xCancel').on('click', function() {
  $('.setting').slideUp(100);
  $(this).hide();
});

$('.set1').on('click', function() {
  $('#xCancel').show();
  $('.settbox').slideDown(100);
});
```

Just follow [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and make things easier. I mean if you need to do the same operation for more elements, why you can't use class as universal selector?

On youtube are lots of tutorials or you can visit jQuery documentation website.

Comment: I want to say thank you, RamoFX, for helping me out in the middle of crisis, but now i'm stuck with this problem "this.$section.on is not a function"

Comment: I've just edited the answer, check it please.

Comment: I manage to make it dry and function based on your advice, Thank you RamoFX. :)

Comment: @DavidEscamilla no problem, just keep it simple ;)